# How to get error message from soap response in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I used Jax-ws web services and **generated client code using wsimport (Java API)** from wsdl. When I execute one request using **SAOP UI** then I got following output.

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Error>Cannot create a new Goal for Receiver with Id : 3,as a Goal already exists </SOAP-ENV:Error>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to fetch above error message using **java** as it is **not coming in response object**. I tried using **Binding Provider but no luck**. Any help to get this message will be appreciated.

Comment: Parse the response XML and look for the child text for the <SOAP-ENV:Error> tag.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for the response but as I told that I am not getting this xml in response object when I am executing service using java code (Client Code).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.  You cut & pasted XML above - are you receiving that or not?

Comment: @duffymo I mentioned in question that "When I execute one request using SAOP UI then I got following output" means xml. But when I tried to execute same request using client code then response object is coming as null as its not part of response object. In that case we need to fetch it from response header but that message is also not coming in response header map. So my question is how to get it?

Comment: Please, show how do you doing generate it with wsimport.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the WS Engine you are using, you will receive an exception when a SOAP Fault happens. You will then be able to get the message from that exception object.

Comment: Thanks.. But how to do it? Please provide reference link that will be useful for me.

Comment: Which WebService Engine are you using?

Comment: To generate client code I used Java's default command i.e. wsimport

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceException.html

You should be catching this exception.

Comment: Web Service is not throwing any exceptions and from response header I am getting status code as 200 which means success. So it will not work.

Comment: Status code 200 comes from the http transaction, which means the request was properly serviced (from a protocol point of view), whereas we are looking at failure from a logical point of view (unexpected response). If you can show your code, it will be easier to debug, IMO.